# Issue with User Defined Table type in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a user defined table type as below

```
CREATE TYPE [emp_TT] AS TABLE 
(
 em_number            char(12),
 email                varchar(50),
 emergency_relation   char(32),
 option1              char(16),
)
GO
```

It got created under the Types as

[image]

And trying to use them in my stored procedure like

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF]
 @emp_TT AS emp_TT READONLY
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 UPDATE e
 SET e.email                 = t.email,
     e.emergency_relation    = t.emergency_relation,
     e.option1               = t.option1,
     FROM [afm].[em] e 
  INNER JOIN @emp_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id

  INSERT INTO [afm].[em](email, emergency_relation, option1, em_id)
  SELECT t.email
    , t.emergency_relation,t.option1
    , t.em_id
 FROM @emp_TT t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [afm].[em]
                WHERE em_id = t.em_id)
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END;
```

When I  execute the stored procedure it is throwing the error like

`Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type emp_TT.`
`Parameter or variable '@emp_TT' has an invalid data type.`

`Must declare the table variable "@emp_TT".`

`Must declare the table variable "@emp_TT".`

Please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: i don't know what you are going to do.. just remove this first. from emp_TT AS emp_TT READONLY to emp_TT   emp_TT READONLY use @ sign at emp_TT variable.

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedure?   Without that information, the issue cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Use schema `afm` like `afm.emp_TT` in line 2 as shown below

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF]
 @emp_TT AS afm.emp_TT READONLY
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 UPDATE e
 SET e.email                 = t.email,
     e.emergency_relation    = t.emergency_relation,
     e.option1               = t.option1,
     FROM [afm].[em] e 
  INNER JOIN @emp_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id

  INSERT INTO [afm].[em](email, emergency_relation, option1, em_id)
  SELECT t.email
    , t.emergency_relation,t.option1
    , t.em_id
 FROM @emp_TT t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [afm].[em]
                WHERE em_id = t.em_id)
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE [emp_TT] AS TABLE 
(
 em_number            char(12),
 email                varchar(50),
 emergency_relation   char(32),
 option1              char(16)  --Removed , here
)
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF]
 @emp_TT AS emp_TT READONLY
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 UPDATE e
 SET e.email                 = t.email,
     e.emergency_relation    = t.emergency_relation,
     e.option1               = t.option1 --Removed , here
     FROM [afm].[em] e 
  INNER JOIN @emp_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id

  INSERT INTO [afm].[em](email, emergency_relation, option1, em_id)
  SELECT t.email
    , t.emergency_relation,t.option1
    , t.em_id
 FROM @emp_TT t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [afm].[em]
                WHERE em_id = t.em_id)
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END;
```

Execute Stored procedure like below

```
DECLARE  @emp_TT AS [emp_TT] 

 INSERT INTO @emp_TT 
 SELECT 'Your All Values'

 EXEC [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF] @emp_tt
```

Answer (score -1):

you will need to declare it ..like below,before using it

```
DECLARE @emp_TT AS emp_TT

INSERT INTO @emp_TT 
 ALL VALUES
```

Now finally , you can pass that to Stored Proc

```
exec [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF] @emp_tt
```